# Changing vspaces around section headings

Tags: spacing, sectioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tune space around section headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15596/tune-space-around-section-headings)

How would one go about setting values for the vspaces above and below section titles?

I don't like the way the space above section headings is smaller than the space below. I think the reverse might look better.

Comment: Use the `titlesec` package.

Comment: As default the space below *is* smaller. So make a minimal example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I found some titlesec code that was adding vspace globally when I only wanted it locally. Thing is, the code was written ages ago because it was to add a subheader for the very first section, so all this time (now on section 10), i've been thinking it was the default. Doh!