# Reduce space before header in scrbook class

Tags: spacing, sectioning, scrbook

In srcbook class, no matter how i set top margin (neither `geometry` nor    `\addtolength` work) it always adds huge space before header. Some people suggested to change `@makechapterhead` definition but `scrbook.cls` contain several entries and i don't know which one i have to change.

Comment: Your title says "header" but your question deals with "headings". Be aware that these two terms don't have the same meaning.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15596/tune-space-around-section-headings

Comment: @Thorsten: good point, i meant header like in question title, i'll edit the wrong word.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you don't mean “headings”? I have quite some trouble imagining “huge space before header”. Maybe you could describe your problem in a little more detail? Maybe you could also add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: I know it sounds strange but while i can move headings without problems header seems fixed. I don't have the source .tex on this pc but it's a slightly edited version of labbook template from CTAN (that is a scrbook.cls with changed sectioning names).

Comment: So what you're actually saying is that you're using the [`labbook`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/labbook) class? You should add an MWE when you have access to your file again (and I still don't know what you mean exactly…)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but i just found that it was not LaTeX's fault but a problem with margin settings on my printer.

Answer (score 1):

The KOMA-script classes `scrbook` and `scrreprt` use `\chapterheadstartvskip` inside the definition of the headings for `\chapter`, `\part`, `\addchap`, `\addpart` and their star-variations to insert vertical apace before the chapter heading and the `labbook` class inherits these setting. The default definition is `\addvspace{4ex}`; if you want to change this value, redefine the command; the following example shows the necessary redefinition to suppress any extra vertical space between the top margin and the chapter heading (the `geometry` package with its `showframe` option was only used to serve as visual reference):

```
\documentclass{labbook}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\chapterheadstartvskip{\addvspace{-4ex}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\experiment{Test Experiment}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]